# Grouping common values from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple arrays in javascript with same number of elements.  I want to find common values and group them together into separate arrays like the following (using javascript and jquery) ...

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,5]
[1,2,3,6]
[1,2,4,3]
```

I want the following result:

1 / 2 / 3 / 4,5,6
1 / 2 / 4 / 3

This should result in two separate sets of combinations as above. Below would not be correct:

1 / 2 / 3,4 / 3,4,5,6

because no arrays of [1,2,4,5] and [1,2,4,6] exist.

Here's my code

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cb4" value="1,2,3,4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cb4" value="1,2,3,5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cb4" value="1,2,3,6" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cb4" value="1,2,4,3" />

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    combos[i] = [];
}
$('input.cb4:checked').each(function(){
    var nums = this.value.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(nums[i], combos[i]) == -1) {
            combos[i].push( nums[i] );
        }
    }
});

var bets = '';
for (i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
    combos[i].sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
    bets += combos[i] + ' / ';
}
```

The string bets has the value of: "1 / 2 / 3,4 / 3,4,5,6".  Again, this is not correct since there are no values of 1,2,4,5 or 1,2,4,6.

Comment: Are you desired results in arrays?  or in strings?

Comment: What are you defining as the 'optimal' result?  The most condensed version?  For instance, should the result of `[1,2,3,4];[1,2,3,5];[1,2,3,6];[1,2,4,4];[1,2,4,5]` be `1/2/3/4,5,6;1/2/4/4,5` or `1/2/3,4/4,5;1/2/3/6`?  Can you provide any more hints as to the nature of the arrays and possible results that would eliminate some more of these complicated scenarios?  Are we talking a handful of arrays or 1000's of arrays, for instance?  Is there only one 'correct' answer or any combination will do?  Can you explain the purpose behind this, and perhaps there is a simpler way?

Comment: Result can be either array or string.  Yes, optimal result is combining all arrays as much as possible.  We're talking about less than 100 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to sort your input arrays into a one-to-many tree structure, i.e. {1,[{2,[{3,[4,5,6]},{4,[3]}]}

Whether you choose to use this structure "as-is" or transform it to strings, it holds the information you want.

Use a basic prototype like:

```
oneToMany = function(a, b) {
  branch = a;
  leaves = new Array();
  for each x in b {
    leaves.push(x).;
  }
}
```

Then nest this until you have the structure I described.

My apologies for syntactical error as I'm answering this from a poor smart-phone. I will fill you in with a better example if you leave of a comment about it. I hope you got my point anyway.